# Typescript, complex objects and uniontypes

Tags: typescript, jwt

I am very new in Typescript. I got along quite well so far but the complex objects I do not understand yet so correctly.
I am currently trying to decode a token via jsonwebtoken. Of the result I need a special field (**kid**).

My code so far:

```
const decodedToken: string | { [key: string]: any } = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
```

but now I really have problems to access the kid field. In ES5 i would do something like this decodedToken.kid

But the jwt.decode function is returning a uniontype of string and complex object which I do not understand.

```
export function decode(
    token: string,
    options?: DecodeOptions,
): null | { [key: string]: any } | string;
```

I understand the return value as follows. I get either null a string or an object with multiple keys and their values of type any.
How am I now able to access the object's **kid**?

Any help is very welcome

Comment: type guards https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html, guar agains `null` and `string` and you can then access `kind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is [type-test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) your way to one type:

```
if (typeof decodedToken === 'string') {
  // Here it's definitely a string
} else {
  // Here it's definitely an object
}
```

This is what you should do anyway (assuming that the type signature for `decode` is correct) since `"somestring".kid` will not produce correct output.

Iff you *know* that this will only ever return an object (because `decode` is a library function and you will only ever put in objects, so you will only receive objects) then you can inform TypeScript of your certainty with a type cast instead:

```
const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true}) as { [key: string]: any };
```